# how to filter null values from map in Dart

Tags: dart

Following the map, having both key-value pair as dynamic, Write a logic to filter all the null values from Map without us?

Is there any other approach than traversing through the whole map and filtering out the values (Traversing whole map and getting Entry Object and discarding those pairs) ?

**I need to remove all values that are null and return map**

```
Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
 return {
  'firstName': this.firstName,
  'lastName': this.lastName
};
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use [`removeWhere`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.2/dart-core/Map/removeWhere.html) on `Map` to remove entries you want to filter out:

```
void main() {
  final map = {'text': null, 'body': 5, null: 'crap', 'number': 'ten'};

  map.removeWhere((key, value) => key == null || value == null);

  print(map); // {body: 5, number: ten}
}
```

And if you want to do it as part of your `toMap()` method you can do something like this with the cascade operator:

```
void main() {
  print(A(null, 'Jensen').toMap()); // {lastName: Jensen}
}

class A {
  final String? firstName;
  final String? lastName;

  A(this.firstName, this.lastName);

  Map<dynamic, dynamic> toMap() {
    return <dynamic, dynamic>{
      'firstName': this.firstName,
      'lastName': this.lastName
    }..removeWhere(
            (dynamic key, dynamic value) => key == null || value == null);
  }
}
```

Comment: key is not nullable, hence no need for 'key==null'

Comment: @Indy9000 Fun fact about answers made before null-safety... they are not made with null-safety in mind. But the question does state "Following the map, having both key-value pair as dynamic" so the key is also `dynamic` so I will change the example to that. :)

Comment: not an attack on the answer, just a hint to the current and future coders who land here...

Comment: @Indy9000 And I am thankful for spotting the error. Sorry if that did not come across in my message. Keep the good work at making sure answers is also relevant in 2022! :)

Answer (score 18):

You can now use a map literal with conditional entries:

```dart
Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
  if (firstName != null) 'firstName': firstName,
  if (lastName != null) 'lastName': lastName,
};
```

Answer (score 5):

I did this to make it easy remove nulls from **map** and **list** using **removeWhere**:
https://dartpad.dartlang.org/52902870f633da8959a39353e96fac25

Sample:

```dart
final data = 
  {
    "name": "Carolina Ratliff",
    "company": null,
    "phone": "+1 (919) 488-2302",
    "tags": [
      "commodo",
      null,
      "dolore",
    ],
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": null,
        "favorite_fruits": [
          'apple', null, null, 'pear'
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Pearl Calhoun"
      },
    ],
  };

void main() {
  // From map
  print('Remove nulls from map:\n' + data.removeNulls().toString());
  // From list
  print('\nRemove nulls from list:\n' + [data].removeNulls().toString());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The limitation of **removeWhere** is that it does not check for nested values. Use this recursive solution if you want to remove all keys in the hierarchy.

```
  dynamic removeNull(dynamic params) {
    if (params is Map) {
      var _map = {};
      params.forEach((key, value) {
        var _value = removeNull(value);
        if (_value != null) {
          _map[key] = _value;
        }
      });
      // comment this condition if you want empty dictionary
      if (_map.isNotEmpty)
        return _map;
    } else if (params is List) {
      var _list = [];
      for (var val in params) {
        var _value = removeNull(val);
        if (_value != null) {
          _list.add(_value);
        }
      }
      // comment this condition if you want empty list
      if (_list.isNotEmpty)
        return _list;
    } else if (params != null) {
      return params;
    }
    return null;
  }
```

#### Example:

```
  void main() {
    Map<String, dynamic> myMap = {
      "a": 1,
      "b": 2,
      "c": [
        3,
        4,
        null,
        {"d": 7, "e": null, "f": 5}
      ],
      "g": {"h": null, "i": null},
      "j": 6,
      "h": []
    };
    print(removeNull(myMap));
  }
```

#### Output:

```
{a: 1, b: 2, c: [3, 4, {d: 7, f: 5}], j: 6}
```

#### Note:

> If you want an empty map and list when their child has null values, comment out an empty check for map and list in the code.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to use [removeWhere](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.0/dart-core/List/removeWhere.html) function

```dart
    Map<String, dynamic> map = {
      '1': 'one',
      '2': null,
      '3': 'three'
    };

    map.removeWhere((key, value) => key == null || value == null);
    print(map);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the method I am using with Flutter 3:

```dart
Map<String, Object?> removeAllNulls(Map<String, Object?> map) {
  final data = {...map};
  data.removeWhere((key, value) => value == null);
  for (final entry in data.entries.toList()) {
    final value = entry.value;
    if (value is Map<String, Object?>) {
      data[entry.key] = removeAllNulls(value);
    } else if (value is List<Object?>) {
      final list = List.from(value);
      for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        final obj = list[i];
        if (obj is Map<String, Object?>) {
          list[i] = removeAllNulls(obj);
        }
      }
      data[entry.key] = list;
    }
  }
  return data;
}
```

Usage:

```dart
var jsonData = jsonDecode(jsonEncode(example.toJson()));
jsonData = removeAllNulls(jsonData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, just like I did, someone might come looking, for How to remove null fields from a model that will be sent to the API using retrofit and dio in flutter
Here is what I used to remove null values from the Model object

> @Body(nullToAbsent: true)

For example

```
@POST("/shops")
Future<Shop> createShop(@Body(nullToAbsent: true) Shop shop);
```

*The **nullToAbsent** param does the trick*

Answer (score 0):

***Remove null from JSON Using Dart Extension Method***

```
extension JsonExtension on Map<String, dynamic> {
         Map<String, dynamic> get removeNull {
         removeWhere((String key, dynamic value) => value == null);
         return this;
      }
    }

final data = {
  "hello":null,
  "world":"test"
};

void main() {
    print(data.removeNull);
}
```

Output

```
{world: test}
```